# Suggestion for a weekly newsletter

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, feed

After using SO for a while you soon notice that some questions are raised because the OP hasn't read the manual, others by not googling, and some (usually by higher rep members) cause your brains to re-evaluate your understanding of what you read in manuals, API tutorials or Wikipedia. This is way more refreshing than any magazine.

RSS feed tools tends to produce too much traffic. There are ways to filter by tag or vote count, but not by writer rating. Available book tools give a more static view on the comunity.  Using the monthly data dump sounds a bit of overkill and too static.

Has anyone tried to or come across a way to produce a weekly report from SO with more detailed parameters?

example feed:

```
SELECT * FROM question AS q
WHERE (q.user.rating BETWEEN n and m) and
      (q.answerCount > 2) and 
      (q.time > NOW()-9days) and (g.time < NOW()-2days)
ORDER BY q.user.rating/max(q.user.rating)+q.votes/max(q.votes) DESC
LIMIT TO 3 best answers
LIMIT TO FIRST 40 pages OF TEXT
> newspaper.pdf
> e-mail on friday
```